# How a method without function name is connected with a particular HashMap

Tags: java

Have a look at this code:

```
 private static Map< String, Method > supplierFunctionMap = new HashMap< String, Method >();
    static
    {
        try {
            //ARP
            supplierFunctionMap.put( "206175-200", SupplierConfiguration.class.getDeclaredMethod("asd", String.class));
            supplierFunctionMap.put( "206175-210", SupplierConfiguration.class.getDeclaredMethod("asd", String.class));
            supplierFunctionMap.put( "206175-998", SupplierConfiguration.class.getDeclaredMethod("asd", String.class));
            //ADD new suppliers below
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in Key / Value of Hashmap. Maybe Key or Value not existing or something else is wrong.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The code under `static{` 
is somehow connected with the `hashmap`.
Because If I call this:

```
supplierFunctionMap.get("206175-200").invoke(null, supplierNumberAndAdmnr);
```

Then the `getDeclared` method is called.

Can somebody explain why `static{`  like this can be declared and how it gets connected with the `hashmap`?

Comment: Reflection is slow, hard to debug, and cannot be optimized by the JIT compiler.  You would be better off with a `Map<String, Function<SupplierConfiguration, String>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your `supplierFunctionMap` is `static`. The `static` block is just adding items to the `HashMap`. `static` variables and any `static` blocks are initialised and executed upon class loading.

The static block is not *connected* to the `HashMap`, just your code indentation is wrong. You could put the `static` block further down.

The only *connection* is that the `static` block is adding items to the same `HashMap`.